# Tool tip /Qtip (mouse over) for Property grid row values in Extjs 3.4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I want to put Tool tip /Qtip (mouse over) for Property grid row values but nothing seems working.. i tried the below code but of no use.. please get me through what i am doing wrong..

```
Ext.getCmp('PropertyGrid').getView().on('render', function(view) {
        addToolTip(view);
    });
    function addToolTip(view){ debugger;
        view.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
            target: view.el,
            delegate: view.cellSelector,
            trackMouse: true,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            listeners: {
                beforeshow: function updateTipBody(tip) {
                    var gridColums = view.getGridColumns();
                    if(tip.triggerElement.cellIndex<0){
                        return false;
                    }
                    var column = gridColums[tip.triggerElement.cellIndex];
                    var val=view.getRecord(tip.triggerElement.parentNode).get(column.dataIndex);
                    tip.update(val);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use customRenderers to insert tooltip, fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/290